# Is there a way to check when the Recording was last accessed?

Tags: twilio

I could not find a way to get last_access_date for a recording. The following API call returns dateCreated/dateUpdated
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording

Is there a way to get lastAccessDate for a recording?

Comment: Hey, Twilio employee here. There is no ```last access date``` attribute in the Recording resource, have you considered programming a log of this yourself? What led you to believe there was a ```last access date``` attribute on this resource?

Comment: I just want to know if there is a way to access the last access date for recording.

Our use case: We forward the recording URL to our clients and we need to know if they accessed the recording. Is there any way for us to get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Last accessed date is not something we currently include in the Recording resource details.  If you are sending the Twilio recording URL direct to your customers then there is isn't a way to tell when they last accessed the file.  You could put an arbitrary lifetime on the file (eg we delete it after X days), but that may not be the best use case.

A better approach might be to, instead of giving them the direct URL, give them a URL that goes through your own web application and them redirects them to the recording URL.  This would allow you to track when the customer has last accessed the file (because they would have to go through your URL).

Of course with using a redirect, it would not be hard to find out the URL you have redirected them to and go around your app if they wanted to.   In that case you might have to consider downloading the recording into your system and having your customers download it directly from you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response Devin.